# An error exception appears (Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I resolved the problem, it was in the based class of the forms, I checked the error details and I found the reason. Thank you very much all.

---

I am trying to create a form at run time, I am loading the form name from my database, and when the user and save it in the menu item tag as a string. When the user clicks the menu item, it calls LoadForm function to create the form. But unfortunately I got the following error:

**Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.**

the error occurred in the following line of the function:

```
Return DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(FormType), frmBasedChiled)
```

I wrote the function below, and I am using VB.NET 2010, can you help me please?

** The form **frmBasedChiled** is a special form class that I created, and I inherited all my project forms from it.

```
    Private Function LoadForm(ByVal FormName As String) As frmBasedChiled

    Dim FormType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetTypes.Where(Function(a) _
        a.BaseType() = GetType(frmBasedChiled) AndAlso a.Name = FormName.ToString).FirstOrDefault

    If FormType Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Return DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(FormType), frmBasedChiled)
End Function
```

Comment: There should be an inner exception. Can you use the debugger to check?

Comment: @ ChaosPandion I used the debug, this is the debug error

Comment: Any reason this is tagged with C#?

Comment: Always include full error details. If the Inner Exception is Null we want to know that.

Comment: I wrote the error message, I checked the FormType object, it is not null

Answer (score 0):

TargetInvocationException indicate that you're trying a cast operation on a wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem, it was in the based class of the forms, I checked the error details and I found the reason. The reason was in the constructor, I have an imagelist control, and I set the form icon to an icon in the imagelist. I removed the line that assigning the icon and it is working properly now. Thank you very much all.